# Autoscale Cadence clients to consume millions of Activities or run millions of workflow instance

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

We have millions of Activities to run or say millions of workflow instance getting created.
Can we create multiple instances of Worker or run worker with multiple thread.

Basically, I want to know, if we have millions of activities to perform or millions of workflow instance getting created. How can we autoscale.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions here:

> Can we create multiple instances of Worker or run worker with multiple thread.

Yes, absolutely. The way you scale out the load is by adding more worker processes.

> can we autoscale?

Autoscaling is possible by watching **schedule to start** latency of activity and workflow tasks. This latency represents the time a task spent in a task queue before being picked up by a worker. Ideally, if there are enough workers it is expected to be zero. But if workers cannot keep up with the load, it is going to grow as tasks being backlogged in the queue.